# In a Excel file how to find the background color of a cell using openpyxl (Python)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, background-color

```
`wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx',data_only=True)
fs_count_row = fs.max_row 
fs_count_col = fs.max_column 
for a in range(1,fs_count_row):
    cell_color = fs.cell(column=1, row=a)
    bgColor = cell_color.fill.bgColor.index
    fgColor = cell_color.fill.fgColor.index`
```

Tried using the above code. However, it works fine for some cells and give wrong output for some other cells. Can I know the reason why?

Comment: You should really look at the fill object, colours are not always set using indices.

Answer (score 3):

Column number was fixed to **1** always, that's why code is not picking up the cells outside of the first column. **Loop both rows and columns**. Updated code below. I've added a print statement to provide the fgcolor and bgcolor of all the active cells along with the cell information. In addition, I've added a condition to ignore the blank cells where there is no foreground or background color.

**Input:**

```
Cell A1 = Yellow
Cell A2 = Blank
Cell B1 = Black
Cell B2 = Red
```

**Code:**

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Excel.xlsx',data_only=True)
fs = wb.active
fs_count_row = fs.max_row 
fs_count_col = fs.max_column 
for row in range(1,fs_count_row+1):
    for column in range(1,fs_count_col+1):
        cell_color = fs.cell(column=column, row=row)
        bgColor = cell_color.fill.bgColor.index
        fgColor = cell_color.fill.fgColor.index
        if (bgColor=='00000000') or (fgColor=='00000000'):
            continue
        else:
            print("Background color index of cell (",row,column, ") is", bgColor)
            print("Foreground color index of cell (",row,column, ") is", fgColor)
```

**Output:**

```
Background color index of cell ( 1 1 ) is 64
Foreground color index of cell ( 1 1 ) is FFFFFF00
Background color index of cell ( 1 2 ) is 64
Foreground color index of cell ( 1 2 ) is 1
Background color index of cell ( 2 2 ) is 64
Foreground color index of cell ( 2 2 ) is FFFF0000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. However, i was trying to find only coloum 1 cell value for all the rows. That's why i had used fixed column.

Comment: In the column one only i faced the issue i have mentioned above.

Comment: why is all the background colors are taken as 64 even though it has cell colors to be yellow black and red

Comment: How to determine the difference between white and blank cell. basically difference between different between each background color

Comment: Please refer documentation in "https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/colors.html" which explains the meanings of all indexes and it's colors. Code returns '00000000' if the cell is blank and for any colors it returns the appropriate index.